# Wants to connect oledb with mysql in ssis

Tags: mysql, ssis, oledb

I am working on a project where i have to get data from MySQL using OLEDB data source. I am facing a issue while connecting Ole db data source with MySql. I am using VS2015 version and i want to connect from SSIS to Mysql db using OLEDB.

Comment: Which problem do you have? Can you explain it in more detail, please? Could you tell us what you tried to do?

Comment: i want to apply a cozyroc solution in which i want to get data from mysql db and then create their csv's using flatfile option in ssis, but the issue is i have to map only one column  that is thunk column and i want to delete the remaining column from the input side as well as output side. ADO Net source won't allow us to delete columns from the output end but OLEDB allows us to delete, so i want to use OLE DB as my data flow source.

Comment: @Saad what do you mean `won't allow us to delete columns from the output end`? A *source* doesn't delete anything. It returns the results of whatever query you use. Even if you use `select *` to return all columns you can simply *not* use any columns you don't need

Comment: @Saad as for using an OLEDB connection for MySQL, you do it the same way as any other OLEDB connection. You have to install the OLEDB provider you want first. After that, it will appear as a choice in the OLEDB source's providers

Comment: @Saad the question doesn't make much sense as it is. Are you asking how to use an OLEDB source? Why not the ADO.NET source? It *does* allow you to specify a query after all. Or are you asking how to configure the Flat File destination?

Answer (score 2):

There is no native OLEDB connection for MySQL. You either need to set up an ODBC connection, or use the Microsoft OLEDB Provider for ODBC Drivers, which encapsulates an ODBC driver to make it OLEDB-compliant.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-odbc?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand your question, you want to connect to MySQL database using the OLE DB connector in SSIS.

There is a way to do it (worked for me at least).

**Prerequisites:**
First, you need to install the MySQL ODBC connector - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ (keep in mind you need the x32 bit version since Visual Studio runs in x32 mode). Then create a system DSN with your MySQL database properties.

1. Go to Visual Studio SSIS and create new connection manager for OLE DB.
2. Change the *Provider* to *MSDataShape*
3. In the field *Server or file name* enter the DSN you have already created.
4. Choose *Use a specific user name and password* and enter your database credentials.

After that, you can test if your connection has succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download MySQL .Net Connector to be able to connect to MySQL Server:

- [Download Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html)

For additional information you can refer to the following links:

- [Connect to a MySQL Data Source (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)
- [How to Connect to MySQL in SSIS](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/connect-mysql-ssis-60851.html)

---

Also, You can download MySQL ODBC Connector and use ODBC instead of OLE DB:

> Connector/ODBC is a standardized database driver for Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, and Unix platforms

*Download Link:*

- [Download Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)