# using OleDbConnection with mysql server

Tags: mysql, vb.net, oledb

So I just migrated an Access Database to a MySql Database.
I wan't to know if it's possible to use the OleDbConnection with MySql server.

Here's what I want to use :
`New OleDbConnection(Provider=WHAT_HERE;Data Source=127.0.0.1,3306;Initial Catalog=*****;User ID=*****;Password=****)`

I know that there is MySqlConnection, but since this is a big, old project, I don't want to re-do all the coding.

Comment: You can't use `OleDbConnection` with `MySQL`, you need to use `MySqlConnection`. You'll have some changes to make unfortunately.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,7523,7703#msg-7703 and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767350/wants-to-connect-oledb-with-mysql-in-ssis#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20native%20OLEDB,to%20make%20it%20OLEDB%2Dcompliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you switch to `MySqlClient` instead of `OleDEb`. It's really not a big deal to do so. Hopefully you have imported the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace at the project level, so you could just remove that import and every usage of an `OleDb` type will be flagged. You can basically use *Find & Replace* to change all the `OleDb` types to `MySqlClient`, e.g. find `OleDbConnection` and replace with `MySqlConnection`.

There is no first-party OLE DB provider for MySQL. There may be third-party options but I'm not aware of any specifically. There is the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers, so you could use that to connect to the MySQL ODBC driver, but that seems like a brittle solution to me.

Given that converting to `MySqlClient` is not especially onerous, I'd stick with that. One gotcha that you might want to be careful of is that, if you don't have `Option Strict On` (which you ABSOLUTLEY should) then there may be instances where creation of a `MySqlParametrer` will accept an `OleDbType` without a compilation error but will behave incorrectly at run-time. Be sure to find ALL instance of the characters "oledb" in code.