# How to connect to MySQL server from Powershell using only .Net methods which have already present in Windows 10 (and, ideally, in Windows 7)

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell

I try to use next script

```
$connectionString = "Provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;Server=192.168.0.70;Uid=sqluser;Pwd=secret;"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectionString)
$connection.Open()

# Create database
$createDatabaseQuery = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydatabase;"
$createCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($createDatabaseQuery, $connection)
$createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

# Use Created Database
$useDatabaseQuery = "USE mydatabase;"
$useCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($useDatabaseQuery, $connection)
$useCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

# Create table
$createTableQuery = @"
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    age INT
);
"@
$createCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($createTableQuery, $connection)
$createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

# Add data to table
$insertQuery = @"
INSERT INTO mytable (name, age)
VALUES ('John', 25),
       ('Jane', 30),
       ('Bob', 35);
"@
$insertCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($insertQuery, $connection)
$insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

# Закрытие соединения с базой данных
$connection.Close()
```

but it throws an exception, like:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient is not registered in the machine

Doest that mean that there is no way to connect to MySQL server from Windows 10 Powershell script "out of he box", usinf only .Net methods which have already present in system? I would like to escape installing some additional *.dll or cmdlets, like Powershell SQLServer.
Thanks in advance

P.S. MySQL Server is up and running, because I can connect to it via HeidiSQL and connection works fine.

UPD: The problem is unsolvable. Since you would always need additional software like MySQL/Connector to download and install from Oracle site. You can not install it via Powershell with help of Install-Package command because somehow it is not listed in NuGet repository.
Of cource it is possible to download and install it in silent mode, yet still it is not a solution.
Very bad. Why still there is such a problem to set up a simple connection to database without additional software. Very bad.

Comment: Is this of any help? https://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2021/04/27/mysql-ps-connection/ Or this? https://www.techtrek.io/connecting-powershell-to-mysql-database/

Comment: Unfortunately, it will not help. Because it requires adding additional software.

Comment: It appears that even the Microsoft Oledb driver will require an ODBC driver. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56767439/447901

Comment: thanks. I understand that I need eithe simplysql module installed or MySQL/Connector from *msi package or NuGet Repository